# Creating a scalable 'Application grouping/Hub' in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, grouping

I would like to find an elegant way of creating a 'hub' for applications in WPF (C#).

What I mean is, say, I have three applications AppA, AppB and AppC, which may have very different UIs (and logic) each, What I would like to achieve, is to have one 'landing page' that contains icons for each of the three applications.
Now, when the user clicks on one of the icons, the 'Overall Application' redirects the user to the UI for that specific clicked application.

I can think of two ways to achieve this:

1) Have a MainWindow with 3 images, and on ImageA_Click --> Another Window appears with the UI for AppA.

2) Have a MainWindow with a Tabcontrol that has 3 Tabs (each tab corresponding to each of the 3 Apps) --> Clicking on one tab directs the user to the specific UI for the App clicked.

What I want is to have an architecture that is scalable, meaning, say tomorrow, I have to develop 10 more apps, I want to be able to quickly (and painlessly)  integrate the additional 10 Apps in the overall solution.

What is the best way to achieve this?

(Note that I am using the MVC pattern for each of the Apps - Not sure if that makes any difference)

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design the every app ui in separate page then using frame and navigation service access to them. Like this:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Name="MainFrame"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new HomePage());
             // OR
             MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new App1Page());
             // OR
             MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new App2Page());
             // OR
             MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new App3Page());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. In this scenario with MainFrame, what would be HomePage, App1Page, etc.? Are they separate windows?

Comment: The MainFrame is a container for App contents and you can change the frame content using navigation service. see this [sample](https://github.com/AmRo045/NavigationServiceSample/)